# How can I load a velocity templete from java server side

Tags: java, velocity

I want to load a velocity template from server side like this:

```
 try{  
     Template template = Velocity.getTemplate("common/pageNav.vm", "GBK");  
     Writer writer = new StringWriter();  
     VelocityContext vContext = new VelocityContext(context);  
     template.merge(vContext, writer);  
     return writer.toString();  
  } catch (Exception ex) {  
     ex.printStackTrace();  
     // throw new Exception(ex);  
     return "";
  }
```

But it throws an exception

```
Unable to find resource 'common/pageNav.vm'
```

How can I get string when I run in tomcat.

Comment: Where is "paveNav.m". Is it in resources? In webContent? Where?

Comment: In WEB-INFO , It likes "/WEB-INFO/templates/common/pageNav.vm",  I had configuer the path like :   <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ebs-servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/common/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>  in web.xml.

Comment: And have you tried adding WEB-INF (or WEB-INFO) like "WEB-INF/templates/common/pageNav.m"?

Comment: And is this code intended to be executed on the client side?  In other words are you trying to fetch the template from a server and use it on a client?

Comment: This code shoud execute at sever side, It works like: execute this code and return a string value to client side.

Comment: WEB-INFO should WEB-INF , that's my writting mistake.

Comment: So you actually want to load (and expand) the template **on** the server side, not **from** the server side ...

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to Velocity's web-server support: http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/webapps.html

Another is to figure out why `getTemplate` is not resolving the template.  That's most likely a problem with the relative pathname ... and what it is being resolved against.  The solution will depend on whether the template is in the file system or being loaded via the app's classloader.  (And that will depend on how the VelocityEngine is configured; e.g. what properties you passed to `Velocity.init(...)`.)